# Zooming jQuery Plugin to Zoom the Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, zooming

I need the `jQuery Plugin` to Zoom the Page to maximum 3 level larger and 3 level smaller.

- Selected Zoom should be stored in Cookie / somewhere to display in the same selected Zoom Size even the user refresh the page.
- Website has PopUp also, so my popup page should work with that too.
- It should work with all the browsers like Firefox, Chrome, IE8, Safari, Mac Safari.
- It should work with other devices like IPAD, IPHONE, Android Mobiles, Windows Mobile.

I'm breaking my head to solve this problem, Anyone please suggest a good jQuery plugin / any other libraries to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I just have tried [Zoomooz.js](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/). Works fine for me with FF and IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to do page zooming with jQuery:

```
 window.onload = function() {
 var currFFZoom = 1;
 var currIEZoom = 100;

 $('#In').on('click',function(){
     if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6){//Firefox
         var step = 0.02;
         currFFZoom += step; 
         $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
     } else {
         var step = 2;
         currIEZoom += step;
         $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
     }
 });

 $('#Out').on('click',function(){
     if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6){//Firefox
         var step = 0.02;
         currFFZoom -= step;                 
         $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');

     } else {
         var step = 2;
         currIEZoom -= step;
         $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
     }
 });};


 <input type="button" id="Out" alt="Zoom Out"/>
 <input type="button" id="In" alt="Zoom In"/>
```

Note: I haven't tested this across many browsers.

Comment: Answer should be a jQuery Plugin or any other library because code has some cross browser issue